# dojo opacity in ie9

Tags: javascript, dojo, opacity

I have seen [this bug report](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/12455) for dojo which was fixed in 1.5.2, however even with dojo 1.6 I still cannot get get opacity to work with dojo.style

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/EXzhA/9/

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not a great fix, you can try setting opacity to 1.1 or some non 1 value.  As to what is going on, a very preliminary look at it seems to indicate some strange floating point stuff going on.  Regardless, the DXImage filter doesn't seem to want to accept 100 for opacity, or is unhappy with whatever value dojo cooked up.  Take a look at the value when you set opacity to 1.1 :  filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=110.00000000000001); zoom: 1;

Regardless, opacity values greater than 1 seem to behave reasonably in Chrome and IE9, and work okay for 0 <= opacity < 1

Comment: I can see it works in the fiddle, but using HTML5 tag instead of XHTML seems to be ineffective I have got around this using `dojo.attr(item, 'style', 'opacity:1')`. It's not ideal though