# dojo widget standby not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dojo, internet-explorer-9, opacity

In my application I am using dojo widget standby while request is being processed at server.

It works fine in IE10 and IE11. However,standby flickers and disappears on IE9. Also,when I checked DOM, it showed that standby is present on page but it is not visible or its opacity has become 0.

I found [this](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/12455) but it doesn't seem to be solved in dojo 1.9
then I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243056/dojo-opacity-in-ie9) but answer didn't solve my problem.

Is this a bug in IE9 or standby?
What could get it working on IE9 ?

Comment: what is the exact version(1.9.1, 1.9.7) of dojo in  your code. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frank123/40ad6zyt/1/) which works as expected in IE9. The version of dojo is 1.9.7

Comment: Have you tried your code with Dojo version 1.9.7?

Comment: No. I will try that. But I don't have option to use 1.9.7 in my application.